# What's the purpose of appending an "m" when measureText

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html5-canvas

It is quite common to see code as following when measuring text in canvas

```
w = c.measureText(d.text + "m").width
```

From https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud/blob/master/d3.layout.cloud.js#L233

Why do people append an "m" when measuring text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that this is used here to add extra padding equal to the width of the `m` character.

In JavaScript, using the `+` operator on a string concatenates it (into a string if it isn't already):

```
"Abc" + "m" // "Abcm"
1 + "m" // "1m"
```

This means that if the value of `d.text` was "Hello, world!", `d.text + "m"` would equal:

```
"Hello, world!m"
w = c.measureText("Hello, world!m").width
```

Assuming the width of the `m` character is 5 pixels, the alternative to this approach would be:

```
w = c.measureText(d.text).width + 5
```

However I presume whatever `d.text` is doesn't necessarily have a fixed font size, so using a fixed value could cause problems.

Comment: +1 @James Donelly, you're correct--the "m" adds a bit of trailing space. And you also presume correctly that the font size is usually defined before calling .textMeasure using context.font="14px Verdana".